# What is wrong with my dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, key

I am learning to create dictionaries with Python and I created the one below to take the information of a detainee at the booking center of a local police station. The information is user inputed:

```
local_police = {'Name' : " ",'Phone number' : '','Address' : " ", 'Registered' : ' ','posession' : []} """a dictionary for the suspects details"""

local_police['Name']=raw_input("Enter suspects name:")
local_police['Phone Number']=input("Enter phone number:")
local_police['Address']=raw_input("Enter Address:")
local_police['Registered']=raw_input("Has suspect been registered? Y/N:")
local_police['posession']=raw_input("items in suspect's backpack (seperate each item with a comma):")

print local_police
```

I notice that I can not successfully input any value into the 'Phone Number' key in the dictionary. Can someone please explain why?

EDIT: I would clarify the post further by adding the following:

My expected output is to look as follows:

```
Enter suspects name:thief dude
>>> local_police['Address']=raw_input("Enter Address:")
Enter Address:theif house
>>> local_police['Registered']=raw_input("Has suspect been registered? Y/N:")
Has suspect been registered? Y/N:Y
>>> local_police['posession']=raw_input("items in suspect's backpack (seperate each item with a comma):")
items in suspect's backpack (seperate each item with a comma):gun,knife,puppy
>>> local_police['Phone Number']=raw_input("Enter phone number:")
Enter phone number:111111
>>> print local_police
{'Phone number': '', 'Name': 'thief dude', 'Registered': 'Y', 'Phone Number': '111111', 'posession': 'gun,knife,puppy', 'Address': 'theif house'}
```

> > > 

You would notice that upon printing, two keys were printed for Phone number. One with the value of 111111(value entered by the user)and the other empty:

```
{'Phone number': '', 'Name': 'thief dude', 'Registered': 'Y', 'Phone Number': '111111', 'posession': 'gun,knife,puppy', 'Address': 'theif house'}
```

Comment: you used `input` instead of `raw_input`. As a side note, that initialization in the first line is redundant, you can simply create an empty dictionary: `local_police = {}`.

Comment: raw_input gives the same error

Comment: Which is? we can't guess what error you are getting without seeing it.

Comment: @ZenMournster Can you post the error and what you were expecting as the output?

Comment: What does "successfully input" mean? Do you receive an exception when inserting the input for that field? Or are you simply saying that afterwards when you try `local_police['Phone number']` it returns `''`? In the latter case, as Nenad mentioned in his answer, you are using different keys in the initial definition and in the input thus creating two key-value pairs.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#148>", line 1, in <module>
    local_police['Phone Number']=input("Enter phone number:")
  File "<string>", line 1
    09053608092
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid token

Comment: @ZenMournster Can you please try by removing the string `"""a dictionary for the suspects details"""` which is at the end of first line and then try?

Comment: Use `raw_input`. For security reasons you shouldn't use `input` with Python 2.x anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is Phone number is written with lowercase n in the dictionary but when you ask for input it is written Phone Number with uppercase n.

Comment: this *might* be a valid answer, so I'd edit out the fact that you wanted to post this as a comment (that is **not** a valid reason to abuse answers to post comments!). However the OP mentioned an *error* (without specifying what he means by "error"), and your answer wouldn't explain an exception being triggered but only why the result is not what the OP expects.